# How to start playing DotA?

Tags: dota

I just read the Valve announcement of DotA 2 and in the meanwhile I would like to try DotA.

I have a some questions about it.

1. Where could I buy a digital copy of Warcraft III : Frozen Throne?
2. Is Frozen Throne enough standalone or should I buy other packages?
3. Where can I found a DotA strategy guide good for newbies?

Comment: Are you sure it has to be the original DotA? If you just want to get familiar with the genre, you can play the similar game [League of Legends](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/) for free.

Comment: I would like to try really DotA because I read that DotA 2 will bring all of 100+ heroes and I would like to be ready when DotA 2 will be out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can buy Warcraft III and the Frozen Throne expansion directly from [Blizzard](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/games/war3/) digitally or from an [authorized reseller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009ECGK).
2. You also need to download the map itself.  You can find the Latest Version here: [getdota.com/](http://www.getdota.com/). You're also going to need a good program to [find games](http://www.garena.com/).
3. There used to be an amazing website for this called [dota-allstars.com](http://dota-allstars.com).  Unfortunately it seems that the creator of DotA has [some issues](http://icefrogtruth.blogspot.com/)...

On an unrelated note, if you like the game play I highly recommend [Heroes of Newerth](http://www.heroesofnewerth.com/). As a competitive DotA player myself, I find that HoN has the [closest mechanics](http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/wiki/index.php/DotA_vs_HoN) (as compared to LoL) and many of the same heroes from the original game.

Additionally you don't have the issues of:

- [how to find a game on DotA](http://www.garena.com/), or
- how to get equal level opponents

Comment: That icefrog truth blog was interesting, is there any more information on that?

Comment: @Echo just what's on dota-allstars.com.  Most of what people are talking about is speculation right now, but it is worth noting that the original creator of DotA (Guinsoo) now works on LoL, and that Icefrog is the creator of DotA Allstar (the current most popular version).  Personally I'm a little apprehensive about DOTA2, but I still have HoN so I'm ok with it.

Comment: I tried Heores of Newerth when was in Open Beta. It was really nice, but I would like to start practice DotA to be ready for DotA 2.

Comment: @Drake the mechanics are verry similar, enough so that practicing one really caries over

Comment: I looked to buy a copy but I am not sure now if it is a good idea spend 20/30 euro for Warcraft III only to play a mod. I have to think a bit. In any case thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

1) You probably want Warcraft III Battle Chest. Here is a link to it on amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Warcraft-III-Battle-Chest-Pc/dp/B00009ECGK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009ECGK)

2) No, Frozen Throne is the expansion, you will need the original too.

3) Here is one: http://www.pubarticles.com/article-dota-strategy-guide-for-beginners-1281941321.html