# Where does a new DotA 2 player start?

Tags: dota-2

I recently received DotA 2 as a gift from a friend. It was very generous of him, but I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. It seems like it is even harder than Team Fortress 2 (which is actually very simple once you get the hang of it). [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/how-to-start-playing-dota) similar question does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: I found Dota 2 to be a bit different then LoL, it freaked me out how bad i was compared to my skills in Lol

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Welcome to Dota, you suck.](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=123364699) This aptly titled guide is by far the best for new players to learn Dota2. It's all-encompassing and should have everything you need to get started, but feel free to follow up with additional questions if anything seems confusing.

[Here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=123364976) is another great all-purpose guide. It's a little newer so it's not as finely tuned, but it's incredibly detailed and very thorough.

If you haven't gotten an invite to play Dota2 yet, they are very plentiful nowadays and you can easily grab one from [Reddit's Share Dota2 Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/sharedota2) or [this cool bot](http://steamcommunity.com/id/dota2bot).

Good luck. =)

Comment: dotafire also has some nice very hero specific guides

Comment: "welcome, you suck" is not really a good title, people tend to steer away from discouraging things like that :).

Comment: @JeffreyLin Yes, but it is the singularly most accurate guide out there, both in tone and facts. Getting over your ego is one of the biggest hurdles to actually starting towards getting good at the Dotes.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh You're right. Its very good, compared to the advice my friends gave me (don't play DotA, it sucks, play LoL instead).

Comment: +1 For referencing 'Welcome to DotA...', by far the best guide to learning how to play the game (or any other moba IMHO) in the internet.

Comment: "Welcome to Dota, you suck" is a great guide. Dotafire, on the other hand, features user-submitted content, which means that not all skillbuilds and guides there are equally helpful. You might want to point that out in your answer.

Comment: Also there is a nice calculator and online encyclopedia www.buildota2.com with a design like in game. You create builds there and see other people builds and guides.

Comment: @JeffreyLin That's actually a funny title and very accurate of the truth facing new players. If you just go out there in the wild without any preparation, you'd brace yourself for real insults much worse than this joking one.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Purge's [Welcome to Dota 2, you suck](http://www.purgegamers.com/welcome-to-dota-you-suck) guide, there are also a couple of tutorials on youtube, search for "dota2 tutorials".

here is a 5 min start vid:

here is a 45min vid:

And try to watch some vid of people playing. TotalBiscuit has about 10 Dota2 videos so far, that got me started,this is the first afaik:

A decent way to start is to pick one or two heroes and "focus" on them. Get to learn the game, last hitting etc. You can start with creating your own game with just bots. This will give you some good learning and no "yelling" from other players. I just follow the items guides the games give you.

Then when you feel like you know the basics, start playing Co-op games of 5 players vs 5 bots. Expand the list of heroes you feel good with (start by watching a vid of them being played helps a lot).

And after a few co-op games start playing some real games, enjoy the game and don't be discouraged by players yelling at you.

Comment: It's common for new players to pick heroes to focus on, but I find it's detrimental in the long run. You need to learn what each hero is capable of- I'd suggest not playing more than two or three games with the same hero until you're 100+ games in. Definitely start with a few bot games to learn the mechanics, courier, shop, etc.

Comment: I feel like I should point out, while totalbiscuit's video's are great, and very entertaining, he is absolutely awful. When he's talking through his decisions, he's absolutely showing you a great way to think about the game, but he's clearly a very inexperienced player. So good to start with, but don't follow his advice *too* religiously. Baumi is a good player, once you get a bit of experience and are able to recognise when he's doing a silly fun build.

Answer (score 0):

basically its really simple to start playing dota 2, best moves that you can do is play a lot of games vs bots so you can learns items, heroes, map. Than you can start watching a lot of different streams, for example you can use WePlay dota 2 stream or just find any stream on twitch. Also best idea to look at pros that playing dota on tournaments like starladder, same WePlay league ooooor the international that will be pretty soon enough =) gl in your starts =)